# Fastener Material for Children's Play Structure

Tags: deck, fastener, play-structures

I'm building a back yard play structure for my children. It is composed of some treated lumber (where necessary) and cedar. I'm trying to keep it as "healthy" as I can, which is why I limited the treated lumber to structural members that won't be frequently touched. High-touch surfaces like railings and floors are cedar.

In looking at lag screws and carriage bolts, I was initially going to use galvanized, as these are generally recommended for outdoor use. However, I noticed at the store that all the galvanized fasteners are plastered with lead and cancer warnings. The display even had a "wash your hands after handling" warning. This is probably an overabundance of caution, but for children, I'd prefer to avoid something with a bunch of lead warnings. I noticed the equivalent zinc-plated fasteners had no such warnings.

My concern is, will the zinc fasteners be sufficiently corrosion resistant? I'm in the Midwest USA, so salt isn't an issue, humidity isn't *too* bad, and we don't have earthquakes, hurricanes, etc. Also, this is for children, so I assume the structure has a useful life of about a decade before they lose interest. It doesn't need to withstand daily use for a century.

I also picked up some of those new "structural screws", which seem well regarded, but I still want carriage bolts for some of the heaviest loads, like the swingset beam.

Comment: You noticed a bunch of warnings because the State of California has declared the entire contents of the universe to be hazardous to your health and it all falls under their Prop 65 warning requirements. `</political rant>`

Comment: This warning is for the lawyers. There is" no" lead in zinc galvanizing ( ppm level). Small amounts of iron ,aluminum, ;with a good instrument antimony, bismuth and other stuff. Just like galvanized has always been.

Comment: You could use stainless for longer life , but then you would be exposed to nickel and chrome; hexavalent chrome is one of the most toxic things out there.

Comment: @blacksmith37 held lots of stainless screws in my teeth while building over the last few months...

Comment: As have countless other workers over the years, @SolarMike. As have countless others...

Comment: you can brush cheap clear nail polish over any prominent touchable fasteners, which would lock in heavy metals and prevent corrosion.

Comment: My point is ; if you cab get lead poisoning from galvanized , you can get hexavalent chrome from stainless ( NOT).

Comment: I get that there are lawyers at work here. California has also declared red meat and coffee cancerous. Can anyone answer the suitability of simple zinc plated carriage bolts in my environment?

Comment: You'll find outdoor friendly painted fasteners at your local home store. They might or might not carry warnings, but intuitively, they seem less problematic than galvy.

Comment: `salt isn't an issue, humidity isn't too bad` ... cedar wood is ... cedar corrodes un-galvanized hardware fairly quickly